# dllexport'ing an incomplete class

Tags: visual-c++, dllexport

[EDIT: further digging revealed a different root issue. I'm rephrasing the question, but leaving the old version below, for consistency with the answer by @Leo]

It seems VC++ (both under VS2005 & VS2010) allows me to dllexport classes with missing implementations!  The following code builds fine:

```
// missingimp.h :
class __declspec(dllexport) MissingImp
{
  void DoStuff();   // no implementation anywhere
  void DoMoreStuff();  // neither for this
}

// missingimp.cpp
#include "missingimp.h"
```

The code both compiles and links fine (in dll configuration) - and of course statically linking with the resulting dll fails.
Is this be a bug? is this behavior somehow by design??

[Old question:]

I'm trying to dllexport a class, that has a data member templated on a forward-declared type:

```
// Class2Export.h:

class ForwardDeclared ;

template<class T> class TemplatedClass
{
T *m_ptr;

public:
TemplatedClass() { m_ptr->DoSomething(); }

};

class __declspec(dllexport) ExportedClass
{
TemplatedClass<ForwardDeclared> TemplateForward;
};

// Class2Export.cpp:

#include "Class2Export.h"
```

(This is not a contrived example - in the real code TemplatedClass is a smart pointer, but that seems irrelevant to the issue at hand.)

This code fails to compile, with -

> error C2027: use of undefined type
>   'ForwardDeclared'

That still makes some kind of sense, based on a [reply from MS](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/634361/problems-exporting-a-class-from-a-c-dll?wa=wsignin1.0#details):

> If TemplatedClass has a constructor
>   then a constructor will be
>   automatically generated for
>   ExportedClass. Since ExportedClass is
>   exported the compiler tries to export
>   the constructor but fails to generate
>   code for it because ForwardDeclared is
>   unknown.

But I suspect that is not the ultimate answer, as when I declare (without even implementing!) a ctor for ExportedClass:

```
...
class __declspec(dllexport) ExportedClass
{
ExportedClass();
TemplatedClass<ForwardDeclared> TemplateForward;
};
...
```

both compile **and link** succeed (with a due warning*).  The issue over at MS-connect seems abandoned - perhaps anyone can shed some light over this strange behaviour?

Thanks!

*EDIT: the generated warning is [C4251](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esew7y1w.aspx) :
 class 'TemplatedClass ' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'ExportedClass'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found an answer [in MS forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/1b7e23df-f189-446c-8a88-07ceb8a2fcaf).

I'm linking to it here, in case it's useful to anyone some day.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I've got the wrong end of the stick, the issue is about when the ExportedClass constructor code is generated.

If the ExportedClass constructor code is generated before ForwardDeclared is declared (not forward-declared but properly declared) then you'll get an error, since the ExportedClass constructor implicitly calls the TemplatedClass constructor, and that calls a method on ForwardDeclared which is undefined.

Your final example, the one which compiles and links with a warning, works because the ExportedClass constructor is never defined. (Presumably the warning is that ExportedClass::ExportedClass does not exist. Since nothing actually tries to use it it's just a warning and not an error.) You've avoided the issue there. As it is, that code is not useful as nothing can create ExportedClass (it has no constructor) but if you define the constructor somewhere then everything should work fine, provided ForwardDeclared is declared/defined before then.

If you change your final example to this you should get the errors back again: (All that's added are two braces to give the ExportedClass constructor an empty body)

```
class __declspec(dllexport) ExportedClass
{
    ExportedClass() { } // Error here
    TemplatedClass<ForwardDeclared> TemplateForward;
};
```

And that code is what you are implicitly doing if you don't have a constructor for ExportedClass at all. In these cases the constructor's code is being generated there and then in the header file. On the other hand, when the constructor is declared without a body in the header you are leaving the code to be defined and generated somewhere else.

Comment: Leo - thanks for answering! The generated warning is about the need to dllexport members type, and not about the missing ctor - see my edit above. Moreover - I believe since ExportedClass is, well, exported, the compiler/linker cannot avoid full code generation just because it isn't used locally: it must be available to external clients, unknown at compile/link time

Comment: @Ofek, Yeah, I did think it strange that it'd let you export something undefined... Hmm, but in that case if you just have "ExportedClass();" in the header, where is the constructor definition coming from? Have you checked that anything is really being exported? Perhaps the warning indicates the export isn't happening, which in turn is removing the requirement that the constructor body is defined.

Comment: apparently I was wrong, and the linker allows one to dllexport a class with missing implementations..  See question edits.  Thanks!